# group 2 variables and then delimit the strings

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to group two variables and remove the comma seperated without increasing the number of row
eg:

```
#my dataframe
> df
  g1 g2        g3
1 a1 a2 77.7,81.7
2 a1 a2 77.7,81.7
3 b2 b3     3,1,5
4 b2 b3     3,1,5
5 b2 b3     3,1,5

Expected Output:
  g1 g2   g3
1 a1 a2 77.7
2 a1 a2 81.7
3 b2 b3    3
4 b2 b3    1
5 b2 b3    5
```

I tried some codes below but its unable to group and not comes in expected format. Please help!

Codes:

```
df <- data.frame(g1 = c("a1","a1","b2","b2","b2"), g2 = c("a2","a2","b3","b3","b3"), g3 = c("77.7,81.7","77.7,81.7","3,1,5","3,1,5","3,1,5"))

library(stringr)
s <- strsplit(df$g3, split = ",")
data.frame(V1 = rep(df$g1, sapply(s, length)), V2 = unlist(s))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on [Chris Ruehlemann's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8039978/chris-ruehlemann) answer: you can use the following and it will still work if values reappear.

```
df$g3_split <- unlist(lapply(split(df,df$g1), function(x) unique(unlist(strsplit(x$g3, ","))) ))

df
  g1 g2        g3 g3_split
1 a1 a2 77.7,81.7     77.7
2 a1 a2 77.7,81.7     81.7
3 b2 b3  3,77.7,5        3
4 b2 b3  3,77.7,5     77.7
5 b2 b3  3,77.7,5        5
```

Answer (score 2):

DATA:

```
df <- data.frame(g1 = c("a1","a1","b2","b2","b2"), 
                 g2 = c("a2","a2","b3","b3","b3"), 
                 g3 = c("77.7,81.7","77.7,81.7","3,1,5","3,1,5","3,1,5"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

SOLUTION:

```
df$g3_split <- unique(unlist(strsplit(df$g3, ",")))
```

RESULT:

```
df
  g1 g2        g3 g3_split
1 a1 a2 77.7,81.7     77.7
2 a1 a2 77.7,81.7     81.7
3 b2 b3     3,1,5        3
4 b2 b3     3,1,5        1
5 b2 b3     3,1,5        5
```

If you want to replace `g3`with the new values, just assign `unique(unlist(strsplit(df$g3, ",")))` to `df$g3` instead of `df$g3_split`.

Comment: If you don't want to make the data frame over, you can use ` unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$g3), ",")))`

Comment: This only works if values are not repeated between unique lists

Comment: one issue in the code is what if a number repeats during that time we cant take unique.. is there a way to tackle that?

Comment: well, for future reference, if that is an important caveat why hasn't it been mentioned in the OP? Can you please update the data in the OP to reflect the issue?

Answer (score 1):

An option with `separate_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   mutate( g3_split = g3) %>%
   separate_rows(g3_split) %>%
   distinct(g3_split, .keep_all = TRUE)
```